# code to detect the Android Device's own Ip Address?

Tags: android, ip

I want to know about the code which can detect the Ip address and the Android client name of the Android Device so that use this Ip Address and client name in our application.

Can Anyone Help me please...
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

This will tell you your own IP Andress if you run this on your Android Phone.

```
try{
      InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      System.out.println("IP of my Android := "+ownIP.getHostAddress());
      }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
      }
```

If you want to know the IP address of any the client which binds with your applicaion use

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  // accept connection                                            


                    System.out.println("Remote IP:"+socket.getInetAddress());

                    System.out.println("Remote Port:"+socket.getPort());
```

Comment: What is the `serverSocket` object in your answer? How did you initialize it?

Answer (score 4):

```
public String getLocalIpAddress()
{
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
             }
         }
     } catch (SocketException ex) {
         Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
     }

     return null;
}
```