# How to get the real IP address on Android application?

Tags: android, ip

How to get the real IP address ? 
I use Code below, the result always be 127.0.0.1

```
if (getIpType(context) == IP_TYPE_WIFI) {

    WifiManager wifi_service = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = wifi_service.getDhcpInfo();
    WifiInfo wifiinfo = wifi_service.getConnectionInfo();
    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(dhcpInfo.ipAddress);

} else {

    Runnable IpRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            InetAddress addr;
            String localIp = null;

            try {
                addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                localIp = addr.getHostAddress();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    Thread payThread = new Thread(IpRunnable);
    payThread.start();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305918/code-to-detect-the-android-devices-own-ip-address?rq=1

Comment: Note that "the real ip address" is a concept not so unique. If your phone is attached to some wifi network (e.g. your home wifi), it will have an IP address local to your home network, but will present itself to the outside word with the IP address assigned to the home router. To test the problem with a Windows PC try with an  `ipconfig` from the command line compared to browsing https://www.whatsmyip.org/. I dont' know how to execute the same test with android, but surely there is a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public String getLocalIpAddress(){
   try {
       for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();  
       en.hasMoreElements();) {
       NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
           for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
           InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                }
           }
       }
       } catch (Exception ex) {
          Log.e("IP Address", ex.toString());
      }
      return null;
}
```

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432695/5284441

Answer (score 0):

you cant get the public ip address through the api android applied. the method is send a request to some website which will response infomations about your public ip address, and then parse the result to get the public ip.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use Volley to get the ip from [this](http://checkip.amazonaws.com/) site

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String urlip = "http://checkip.amazonaws.com/";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlip, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            txtIP.setText(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            txtIP.setText("didnt work");
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Is there any limitation of using this api?

Comment: i haven't faced any with 300+ active users, I triggered it only once while app  opening